# Rate of convergence of random variables for weak convergence

Tags: reference-request, probability-theory, definition

Suppose $X_{n}$ be a sequence of random variable that converges to $X$ in distribution. How can we define the rate of convergence? What would be the reference?

Comment: Again, since you are asking for a definition and a reference I have added both those tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

$\alpha_n \stackrel{\rightarrow}{_D} \alpha$,  s.t.

$\alpha_n \stackrel{_D}{\approx} \alpha + \epsilon(n)$,

then the rate of convergence is the convergence rate of $\epsilon(n)$. Eg, in CLT type convergence, the error would be of order $n^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ and the measures would converge at such rate.